# NSArrayController for polymorphic class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, polymorphism, nsarraycontroller, master-detail

I have the following (stripped down) class interfaces:

```
@interface ScriptEvent : NSObject {
  ...
}

@interface SingleLine : ScriptEvent {
  NSString *line;
}

@interface MultiLine : ScriptEvent {
  NSArray *lines;
}
```

Another parent class holds an `NSArray` containing a list of `ScriptEvent`s (which will either be `SingleLine` or `MultiLine`).

In my XIB I have an `NSArrayController` bound to this list of `ScriptEvent`s and I want to set up a master/detail arrangement. So I have an `NSTableView` linking to this `NSArrayController` and I want to show a **different** detail panel depending on whether the selected member of the `NSArrayController` is a `SingleLine` or a `MultiLine`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the selected member is a SingleLine or a MultiLine with:

```
if([objectToCheck isKindOfClass:[SingleLine class]]){
    //Do some staff
}else if([objectToCheck isKindOfClass:[MultiLine class]]){
    //
}else{
    //
}
```